# i want sublime tab width to be 2 to for .rb files and 4 for .js files

Tags: sublimetext3

Is there a way to edit the Preferences.sublime-settings file to reflect different settings depending on the file type?

Here is the code I currently have in the file.

```
{
"detect_indentation": false,
"tab_size": 2,
"translate_tabs_to_spaces": true
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Sublime supports settings based on the syntax of a particular file. While you have a particular file open (for example a Ruby file), select `Preferences > Settings - Syntax Specific` to open up the preferences specific to that type of file.

`Preferences.sublime-settings` sets the overall settings used for everything, and then the syntax specific settings are applied on top. So for example if you only change the `tab_size` setting in the Ruby specific preferences, the tab size will change but all other settings will remain set as they are in `Preferences`.

In your case you should set the `tab_size` setting to whatever you usually use as a default most of the time and then apply syntax specific changes to the syntaxes that you want it to be different in.